# QMAKE / QT5: Platform independent copy command?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

is there a platform independent way in QMAKE to copy files? Currently I use `xcopy` under windows, which is able to handle german umlauts.

```
# Simple "Release" target related copy of compiled .exe file into .compiledOutput folder
# xcopy is windows dependant, but necessary to handle german umlauts

win32 {
    build_pass: CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += xcopy /Y $$quote($$system_path($$absolute_path($$OUT_PWD/release/$${TARGET}.exe))) \
        $$quote($$system_path($$absolute_path($$OUT_PWD/../$${TARGET}/.compiledOutput/)))
    }
    else: build_pass {
        # Do nothing, only copy release build to .compiledOutput
    }
}
```

I know there is `$$QMAKE_COPY` which unfortunately resolves to `copy` for my Qt5.8 setup and `copy` has problems with german umlauts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can try:

1. Replace common Windows cp.exe with xcopy.exe .
2. Make soft- or hardlink of cp.exe to xcopy.exe. And include folder with it before folder with cp.exe in PATH environment variable. Qmake must use your version of cp.exe instead of system.
3. On other systems(rather than Windows) you can emulate xcopy.exe as a symlink or an executable script.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. xcopy in general is working, currently I am searching for a `$$QMAKE_COPY` analog command which resolves to xcopy